# Converting JSON to Dictionary by Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "reserve": {
        "duration": {
            "startTimeUnix": "",
            "startTime": "صبور باشید...",
            "endTime": "۱۳۹۴/۰۹/۰۴ ۱۲:۲۰",
            "endTimeUnix": 1448441400
        },
        "service": null,
        "reserver": {
            "first_name": "مریم",
            "last_name": "موسوی",
            "phone": "09124955173"
        }
    },
    "block": {
        "duration": null
    },
    "is_block": false,
    "taken_time": null,
    "staff": "alireza",
    "service": [
        "O5KLFPZB"
    ]
}
```

And then, I posted it to a Django backend server via AngularJS, then I just get `<QueryDict: {}>` when I use `request.POST`, so, I used `request.body`, after then I gave:

```
b'{
    "reserve": {
        "duration": {
            "startTimeUnix": "",
            "startTime": "\xd8\xb5\xd8\xa8\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb4\xdb\x8c\xd8\xaf...",
            "endTime": "\xdb\xb1\xdb\xb3\xdb\xb9\xdb\xb4/\xdb\xb0\xdb\xb9/\xdb\xb0\xdb\xb4        \xdb\xb1\xdb\xb2:\xdb\xb2\xdb\xb0",
            "endTimeUnix": 1448441400
        },
        "service": null,
        "reserver": {
            "first_name": "\xd9\x85\xd8\xb1\xdb\x8c\xd9\x85",
            "last_name": "\xd9\x85\xd9\x88\xd8\xb3\xd9\x88\xdb\x8c",
            "phone": "09124955173"
        }
    },
    "block": {
        "duration": null
    },
    "is_block": false,
    "taken_time": null,
    "staff": "alireza",
    "service": [
        "O5KLFPZB"
    ]
}'
```

pt

## In views.py

```
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exem

@csrf_exempt
def admin_block_time(request):
    dic = json.loads(request.body.encode("utf-8"))
    print(dic)
```

How can I convert it to Dictionary, although I tried `json.loads()`, but, it didn't work.

Comment: how did it not work? what did you get instead?

Comment: How did you call json.loads()?

Comment: I get nothing when I use print(json.loads(request.body)), isn't it because of b' at first?

Comment: Did you try `request.json()`?

Comment: is `request` a python `requests` `response` object? Then its just `request.json()`.

Comment: request is a django request object so the op can't `.json()` it

Answer (score 3):

Your input is of type `bytes`, therefore `json.loads(your_json)` will raise `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`.

The solution is to decode it with the encoding specified in the `Content-Type` HTTP Header:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(your_json.decode("utf-8"))
{
    'is_block': False,
    'taken_time': None,
    'staff': 'alireza',
    'block': {'duration': None},
    'service': ['O5KLFPZB'],
    'reserve': {
        'service': None,
        'duration': {
            'endTime': '۱۳۹۴/۰۹/۰۴        ۱۲:۲۰',
            'startTimeUnix': '',
            'endTimeUnix': 1448441400,
            'startTime': 'صبور باشید...'
        },
        'reserver': {
            'first_name': 'مریم',
            'phone': '09124955173',
            'last_name': 'موسوی'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its usually `utf-8` but is controlled by the content header, e.g., `content-type 'application/json; charset=utf8`.

Comment: it doesn't work, I added my views.py to the question

Comment: try `json.loads(request.body.read().encode("utf-8"))`. Otherwise it might be python failing to print it.

Comment: This answer is the wrong way around. You use `decode`, not `encode` to convert bytes to a string.